# Return selected rows from dialog with SlickGrid table

Tags: dialog, slickgrid

I created  a view with SlickGrid table in dialog box.
And I could not find out how return the selected rows (checked in check box) into parent view.
I could not find any example to get a clue how implement this.
It looks like when the selection is completed some vent should be fired in dialog view.  And in the parent view this event should be caught. But I do not know how it could be done. 
Any help is appreciated

Here is my code :

## View for dialog box:

@model IEnumerable
@using Newtonsoft.Json

```
<div>
    <div id="myGrid" style="width:350px;height:500px;"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var md = Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model));
    var mdd = md;
    var grid;
    var selectedRows = [];
    var chosenItems = [];
    var data = [];
    var options = {
        enableColumnReorder: false,
        multiColumnSort: true,
        editable: true,
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        asyncEditorLoading: false,
        autoEdit: false,
        frozenColumn: 1
    };

    var colms = [          
    {id: 0, name:"Name", field:"Name",width:200 },
    {id: 1, name:"NDB_No", field:"NDB_No", width:40},
    {id: 2, name:"GrpTypeFlag", field:"GrpTypeFlag", width:40 },
    {id: 3, name:"FdGrp_CD", field:"FdGrp_CD", width:40 }
    ];
    var columns = [];

     $(function () {
         for (var i = 0; i < md.length; i++) {
             var d = (data[i] = {});
             d["id"] = i;
             d[0]= md[i].Name;
             d[1]= md[i].NDB_No;
             d[2]= md[i].IdFdGrpFlg;
             d[3]= md[i].FdGrp_CD;
         }

         var checkboxSelector = new Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn({
             cssClass: "slick-cell-checkboxsel"
         });

         columns.push(checkboxSelector.getColumnDefinition());

         for (var i = 0; i < colms.length; i++) {
             columns.push({
                 id: i,
                 name: colms[i].name,
                 field:  i,
                 sortable: true, 
                 width:colms[i].width
             });
         }

         grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

         grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
             var cols = args.sortCols;
             data.sort(function (dataRow1, dataRow2) {
                 for (var i = 0, l = cols.length; i < l; i++) {
                     var field = cols[i].sortCol.field;
                     var sign = cols[i].sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
                     var value1 = dataRow1[field], value2 = dataRow2[field];
                     var result = (value1 == value2 ? 0 : (value1 > value2 ? 1 : -1)) * sign;
                     if (result != 0) {
                         return result;
                     }
                 }
                 return 0;
             });
             grid.invalidate();
             grid.render();
         });

         grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel({selectActiveRow: false}));
         grid.registerPlugin(checkboxSelector);
         var columnpicker = new Slick.Controls.ColumnPicker(columns, grid, options);
     });
</script>
```

## function calls dialog box:

function dialogUP() {

```
        document.getElementById("dialog-form").innerHTML = '';
        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            position: { my: "right+350 bottom-100" },
            width: 490,
            height: 570,
            resizable: false,
            title: foodSourceName + ': ' + grpName,
            modal: false,

            open: function () {
                var url = '@Url.Action("TestDialog", "TestAtida")';
                url += '/?grpCD_name=' + grpCD + '=' + foodSourceType;
                $(this).load(url);

            },
            buttons: {
                'Cancel': function () {
                    partialFree = 0;
                        $(this).empty(); 
                        $(this).dialog('close'); 
                        $input.focus().select(); 
                }
            }
        });

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears that you're using ASP NET Core MVC.

SlickGrid doesn't have any server side hooks built in. You could use an editor/formatter for the checkbox column, and the checkbox status will simply  be saved to the `data` object.  Or your code can create a list of selected column indexes, if you want to stay with the column configuration that you have posted.
There will be some sort of trigger to kick off the data save, perhaps it's when the dialog is closed, so you'd use an HTML bound event to do that.

It's up to you to persist that data to the server, whether using AJAX and an API controller or perhaps using a regular controller and a POST action.